# Using OnTouchListener and OnLongClickListener interferes with eachother

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener

I have got this button which uses onclicklistener and onlongclicklistener, but also a button which uses ontouchlistener...

the point is button 1 is 0,1 second pressed, button 2 is 2 seconds pressed, button 3 could be pressed for 50 seconds or even more... but button 3 is seen as long click instead of touch on release after 5 seconds, and so it will not trigger my action

I used:

```
    MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,
        View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnTouchListener {

    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnTouchListener(this);

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button3:
         if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
             DoTest1();
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             DoTest2();
                }
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I remove the onlongclicklistener it's working fine..

Any idea's?

Thanks for your support!!!

Comment: You may want to tag what language this question is...

Comment: android... so... i think app inventor... JAVA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `View.setLongClickable(false)` on button 3.

Comment: true, however, returning a  default of false on longclick enables the others to continue :)